# How to put sub-totals next to the item that the sub-total is meant for in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with rows like this:

```
Column C  Totals
Item A    120
Item B    220
Item A    120
Item C    90
Item B    220
Item A    120
Item C    90
```

I'm not sure how to write a SQL statement that can sum this table in this way:

```
Item A  360
Item B  440
Item C  180
```

How can I write a select statement that can sum up the numeric column in that table as displayed above?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: read about `sum` and `group by`

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I looked up 'group by' and that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done by using SUM and GROUP BY:

```
select
    `Column C`
   , sum(Totals) as Total

from
    your_table_name_goes_here

group by
    `Column C`
```

Read more about these functions on the MySQL community site:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: I had forgotten about 'group by'. This solves my problem.